# Determining Parent Element XML C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I'm currently looping over an XML document. Structure shown below (data changed)

```
<activity date="2013-07-05T06:42:37" name="view" host="00.000.00.000">
  <user id="EU-user@user.co.uk" name="U user" memberType="E" />
  <storageObject docId="0000-0000-0000" name="2. Extract Lease - 31.07.2003" size="1903885" fileExtension="pdf">
  <cabinet name="Company Intranet">NG-FGW7XX1Y</cabinet>
    <Matter>0000</Matter>
    <Client>X01659</Client>
    <Author>Joe Bloggs</Author>
  </storageObject>
</activity>
```

What I need to do is loop over each `activity` element, and print the information held in each child element and attribute. Currently I have this

```
        var root = doc.Root;


            foreach (XElement el in root.Elements().DescendantsAndSelf())
            {



                if (el.Value.Equals(""))
                {
                    //don't print anything, just move along, nothing to see here

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(el.Value);
                }
                //Console.WriteLine("  Attributes:");
                 if (el.HasAttributes == true)
                {

                    foreach (XAttribute attr in el.Attributes())
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine(attr.ToString());
                        //   Console.WriteLine(el.Elements("id"));
                    } 


            }

        }
```

Which works to some extent, except that there is no obvious distinction as to where the `activity` element ends (ie, it prints a wall of text once it's finished, and I'd like to be able to distinguish between elements). It also prints the `cabinet` element twice throughout, but as a concatenated version of the child elements, before looping through and printing them out individually. As shown below

```
NG-FGW7XX1Y0000X01659Joe Bloggs
date="2013-07-05T06:42:37"
name="view"
host="00.000.00.000"
id="EU-user@user.co.uk"
name="U user"
memberType="E"
NG-FGW7XX1Y0000X01659Joe Bloggs
docId="0000-0000-0000"
name="2. Extract Lease - 31.07.2003"
size="1903885"
fileExtension="pdf"
NG-FGW7XX1Y
name="Company Intranet"
0000
X01659
Joe Bloggs
```

I need to be able to loop over the individual `activity` element, and print out all the elements and attributes without the concatenated lines. I'd also like to be able to insert a `Console.WriteLine("------");` so I can easily see on the console where each activity ends. Any suggestions?

The reason I'm looping over elements is that some records have additional elements that otherwise wouldn't be found.

EDIT: This is what it should look like

```
date="2013-07-05T06:42:37"
name="view"
host="00.000.00.000"
id="EU-user@user.co.uk"
name="U user"
memberType="E"
docId="0000-0000-0000"
name="2. Extract Lease - 31.07.2003"
size="1903885"
fileExtension="pdf"
NG-FGW7XX1Y
name="Company Intranet"
0000
X01659
Joe Bloggs
```

Comment: Without the concatenated lines? Maybe best to add what you want it to look like to question

Comment: @weston I've added the desired output